# Get maximum id if there are parent id otherwise get all results

Tags: mysql

I have a table and having the following data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_ticket` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_ticket`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_ticket` (`id`, `parent_id`, `ticket_title`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'tyty'),
(2, 0, 'testing'),
(3, 0, 'test from ticket'),
(4, 0, 'test ticket'),
(5, 0, 'test ticket'),
(6, 0, 'test ticket'),
(7, 0, 'test ticket'),
(8, 5, 'test ticket'),
(9, 0, '1 Ticket'),
(10, 0, '2Ticket'),
(11, 2, 'ticket2'),
(12, 2, 'ticket1'),
(13, 0, 'title 1234'),
(14, 0, 'titles 1234'),
(15, 14, 'sample 1234');
```

I need to return  all rows where  id is not present in parent id from the table.
Also if id is present in the parent_id column, I want to get the row having the highest id which matches the parent_id.
i.e. I need to return rows with `id 1, 3,4,6,7,8,9,10, 12,13, 15`.

I tried this sql

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `parent_id` 
FROM  `tbl_ticket` 
WHERE id NOT 
IN (

SELECT parent_id
FROM tbl_ticket
)
```

but it returns value `11` also, instead it should return `12` which is the row having highest id with `parent_id =2`

Comment: why is 5 in your results? 5 is in the parent field for 8

Comment: that was a mistake, i deleted 5. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `5` in your expected output is a typo, as `5` appears in the `parent_id` field for `id=8`, you can get your result by the `union` of two simple queries.

```
select t1.id
  from tbl_ticket t1
    where not exists (
      select 1 from tbl_ticket
        where parent_id = t1.id
    )
    and parent_id = 0
union all
  select max(id)
    from tbl_ticket
    where parent_id <> 0
    group by parent_id
order by id asc
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a78ec/31)

The query is in two parts. the first part gets all the tickets that are not present in another tickets parent_id field, and which themselves do not have a parent (`parent_id = 0`).

The second part of the query looks at those tickets that DO have a parent (`parent_id <> 0`), and for each group of tickets that share the same `parent_id`, selects the one with the `max` id.

The results are then combined with a `union` to give a single result set. Since the two result sets are mutually exclusive, we can use `union all` to skip over the duplicate check.

Comment: If you got time can you explain the sql also?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with `not exists` rather than combining two separate queries.  The advantage is that no duplicate elimination is needed (as is needed when you use `union`):

```
select t.*
from tbl_ticket t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tbl_ticket t2
                  where t2.parent_id = t.id
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from tbl_ticket t2
                  where t2.parent_id = t.id and t2.id > t.id
                 );
```

The first gets all rows that have no parents.  The second gets all rows with the maximum id for a parent.

For best performance, you want an index on `tbl_ticket(parent_id, id)`.

Comment: There's no need for duplicate elimination in the union when the two halves are already mutually exclusive. also, your answer includes the values `11`  and `14` when it should not.

Comment: @pala_ . . . I followed the rules in the text.  11 is there because "where id is not present in parent id from the table".  The 14 was there because I misunderstood the second rule (which is fixed).

Comment: but when parent_id is not zero, select the max id with that parent_id, hence 11 is excluded and 12 included

Comment: @pala_ . . . There is nothing in the question (when I read it) that specifies anything special about `parent_id = 0`.  That in fact is why I wrote an answer.

Comment: It's there to intuit. 0 means no parent so it should only be included if it has no children of its own. And for rows with parents, only the max I'd let parrnt It became clear when the sample output was corrected. Ugh excuse my phone typos